# How to mock a static method inside another static method using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mockito, powermockito

I have a java class named `ParticipantUtils.java` which contains static methods like this:

```java
public class ParticipantUtils {
      
    public static boolean isAlpha(String inputString) {
        if (Character.isLetter(inputString[0]) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static String getNationalNumberJP(String input) {
        if (isAlpha(input)) return input;
        return "Invalid input";
    }
}
```

I'm writing `@Test` to test the function `getNationalNumberJP()` in `ParticipantUtilsTest.java` like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ParticipantUtils.class})
public class ParticipantUtilsTest {
    
    @Test
    public void getNationalNumberJP_input_is_alpha(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ParticipantUtils.class);
        String input = "ABCD";
 
        PowerMockito.when(ParticipantUtils.isAlpha("ABCD")).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals("ABCD", ParticipantUtils.getNationalNumberJP(input));
    }   
}
```

But, this is not working. It is not returning `true` when the function `isAlpha(input)` is getting called.
I'm getting this error at the line `assertEquals(...)`

[image: Error image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the `ParticipantUtils` class. This includes `getNationalNumberJP()`. You did not provide mock behavior for (since you want to test it) and therefore the mock does not know what to do and returns the default value for the return type (which is `null` for reference types). Your problem is not that `isAlpha()` is not returning `true`. If this were the problem, then "Actual" would be "Invalid input" and not `null`.

You do not need to mock here at all. The result of `isAlpha()` would be `true` in your test case anyway.

Comment: "You did not provide mock behavior for (since you want to test it) and therefore the mock does not know what to do and returns the default value for the return type."
What does that mean? I have to provide what to return when `getNationalNumberJP()` is called? How to do that? Also why should we do that when we are testing that function itself?

Comment: You are mocking all methods in `ParticipantUtils`, including `getNationalNumberJP()`. This means you are calling a mocked version of that method. Resolve by simply not mocking at all. It is not needed in your case.